# Uploading multiple images in the same form using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

Here is my controller code and also my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-field">
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</p>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)</p>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UnitPrice)</p>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UnitPrice)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="file" name="image1" />
        <input type="file" name="image2" />
        <input type="file" name="image3" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
}
```

And in the Controller. Don't focus on the content of the action method, just focus on the parameter of type `List<HttpPostedFileBase>`. Is this the right way of doing things? As it is, `images` is null upon submission of the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductModel model, List<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newProduct = Mapper.Map<ProductModel, Product>(model);
            _productRepository.CreateProduct(newProduct);
            _productRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If you could provide a very simple example that would be fantastic.

Comment: It turns out I just needed to modify the View code to use the name of the HttpPostFile collection. Now what is protocol here, do I answer my own question?

Comment: If none of the posted answers gives you correct answer, yes, do post your own answer and mark it. If one of the answer is very close to what you wanted then give what was missing point in comment or edit the answer itself and mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so this is a simple example on how to do it. The end result:

[image]

The HTML markup is a simple form, with a submit button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-field">
        <p>Select pictures:</p>
        <div class="upload-container">
            <div class="upload">
                <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" /> 
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/delete.png")" alt="Remove picture." />
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
}
```

We also needs some jQuery magic so that every time someone adds an image, we let them also add in more as needed. A user can upload N images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentImage = 1;
        $("body").on("change", "input[name='files']", function () {
            var pathToRemoveIcon = "@Url.Content("~/Public/images/delete.png")";
            currentImage = currentImage + 1;
            var htmlToAppend = '<div class="upload"><input type="file" name="files" id="file' + currentImage + '" /><img src="' + pathToRemoveIcon + '" alt="Remove picture." /></div>';
            $('.upload-container').append(htmlToAppend);
        }).on("click", ".upload img", function () {
            if ($(this).parent().siblings().length > 0) {
                $(this).parent().remove();    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Persist the files uploaded.
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: on your OP you had name, description and unit price.  How did you incorporate those in your view and controller action along with the pics?

Comment: Thank you for a simple cross-browser compatible way of doing this!

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two posts they might help

[ASP.NET MVC: ModelBinding Multiple File Uploads to an Array](http://www.heartysoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-ModelBinding-Multiple-File-Uploads-to-an-Array)

[Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)