# How To upload Multiples Files MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need upload multiples files form MVC3. But I don't get the variable on the server. This is my code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Register", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
         <table>
              <tr>
                   <td class="label">@Resources.Global.exemploFotos</td>
                   <td><input type="file" name="file" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" maxlength="3" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                   <td><input type="submit" value="@Resources.Global.enviar" /></td>
              </tr>
         </table>
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload,  FormCollection collection)  
{
      return View();  
}
```

But fileUpload == Null;

Comment: this is nice solution http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Files-In-RAZOR-With-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change name of input to fileUpload. Your file input name is file. You are then looking for fileUpload to populate your IEnumerable of files.

Comment: No problem. Also in general if you are doing file uploads I tend to like http://www.plupload.com/ control.

Comment: Is there anything I can add to this answer to help? Is your issue resolved. If so can you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, to allow cross-browser compatibility for this I would use this answer: [Uploading multiple images in the same form using MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845012/uploading-multiple-images-in-the-same-form-using-mvc3)

It's basically cloning your file upload input whenever someone selects a file in the last cloned file upload input